# Gorm: object mapping

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have two objects, a CarOffer and a Car. A CarOffer is composed of various attributes, one of which references a Car. In other words, I can have multiple CarOffers, multiple Cars, but there is one and only one Car per CarOffer. A Car can be present in multiple CarOffers. Deleting a CarOffer should not delete the car it references, and deleting a Car should not be possible unless all CarOffers referencing it have also been deleted.

Usually, I would just have added a carId attribute to CarOffer, but from the gorm documentation I feel I should use the power of Gorm to add a Car Object to CarOffer, instead of just its id.

However I'm a bit lost, I feel neither 'belongsTo' nor 'hasOne' really map to what I want.

Besides, how would I go to create a new CarOffer?
I would expect to be able to do

```
new CarOffer(carId: 123).save()
```

but instead I feel I must do:

```
new CarOffer(car: Car.get(123)).save()
```

Does that not create one extra request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel neither 'belongsTo' nor 'hasOne' really map to what I want.

You don't want `belongsTo` because that will cause deletes to be cascaded and you said you didn't want that ("Deleting a CarOffer should not delete the car it references").

You could use a `hasOne` or not, that will affect which table has the foreign key in it.

If you don't want to use the `carId` approach, you can do something like this:

```
class CarOffer {
    String attribute1
    int attribute 2
    // etc...

    Car car
}

class Car {
    String attribute1
    // etc...

    // There could be, but does not need to be
    // any mention of CarOffer in this class
}
```

> ...how would I go to create a new CarOffer?

It depends on details in your app that you haven't mentioned but you can do some thing like this...

```
Car c = // ...
CarOffer co = new CarOffer(attribute1: 'something', attribute2: 2112, car: c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 3 questions: 1. I am not saying I don't want to use the carId approach, just that I felt gorm is supposed to handle it for me. Is that the case, or should I use the carId approach? 2. I don't understand how hasOne would work: if hasOne puts a foreignKey in the table Car, and it references a CarOffer, it would mean only one CarOffer can reference a given Car, which is not the case (oneToMany, not oneToOne).

Comment: 3. When I create a CarOffer, the car is typically already created in DB. Hence my question, does your code create 2 requests (getting Car, then creating CarOffer)? Is it possible, using the approach you mentioned, to create a CarOffer by just referencing its id, seeing as it ends up being just an id in the DB? Something like CarOffer co = new CarOffer(att1: 'att1', car: new Car(id: '123')), even though a Car with id 123 already exists ?

Comment: "...just that I felt gorm is supposed to handle it for me" - It can, but doesn't need to.  You seemed to be asking for an alternative to the `carId` approach and I described one.  "...it would mean only one CarOffer can reference a given Car".  If you were going to use `hasOne` it wouldn't be that a car has one offer, it would be that an offer has one car.  "does your code create 2 requests" - Yes.

Comment: And what about new CarOffer(car:new Car(id:123)). Is that possible, if the car with id 123 already exists ? And ultimately, for that usecase, would you recommend storing the whole Car in CarOffer, and relying on gorm, or just the carId ? Thx

Comment: I don't think `new CarOffer(car:new Car(id:123))` makes sense.  That is creating a new `Car` with id of 123, which doesn't seem to be what you want.  That is not querying the database to retrieve the existing `Car`.

Comment: What I meant to say is, what does this syntax produce if a car with id 123 already exists, seeing as carIds are unique ? Does it just add a new CarOffer with a column car_id = 123 (referencing the existing car), or does it produce an error ?

Comment: "what does this syntax produce if a car with id 123 already exists," - In domain classes the `id` property is excluded from mass property binding by default, so `new Car(id: 123)` is effectively the same as `new Car()`.  An exception to that would be if you were using the `assigned` id generator and had configured the `id` with `id bindable: true` in the `constraints` block.

Comment: Thanks for all these explanations, very educational. I marked your answer as accepted. So just to sum up, in the end, you would recommend me using a carId instead of a Car, from the description in the original question?

Comment: "So just to sum up, in the end, you would recommend me using a carId instead of a Car..." - Not necessarily.  Optimizing your object model depends on an understanding of the app and its use cases and an understanding of what your optimization priorities are.  There isn't one way to optimize.  You can optimize for different things.